# Castle Windsor Controller Factory and RenderAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, castle-windsor

I am running into an issue when using my Castle Windsor Controller Factory with the new RenderAction method.  I get the following error message:

A single instance of controller 'MyController' cannot be used to handle multiple requests. If a custom controller factory is in use, make sure that it creates a new instance of the controller for each request.

This is the code in my controller factory:

```
public class CastleWindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private IWindsorContainer container;

        public CastleWindsorControllerFactory(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }

        public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            return container.Resolve(controllerName) as IController;
        }

        public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
        {
            this.container.Release(controller);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know what changes I need to make to make it work with RenderAction?

I also find the error message slightly strange because it talks about multiple requests, but from what I can tell RenderAction doesn't actually create another request (BeginRequest isn't fired again).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the default config for Castle Windsor is a Singleton.  You need to change this  to Transient in your Web.Config or by putting this attribute on your class `[Transient]`.

Comment: You are correct.  The default lifestyle for Windsor components is singleton.

Comment: You can also register it as transient via fluent API http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx?HL=transient#Configuring_components_lifestyle_3 . Using XML for registration is not regarded as best practice.